# Show that the following function is a diffeomorphism of class $C^1$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let $B=\{(u,v) \in \mathbb{R^2} | u>v>0\}$ and let $f:\mathbb{(0,\infty)^2} \to B$ be the function:
$f(x,y)=(\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}y^2,\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}y^2)$. Show that $f$ is a diffeomorphism of class $C^{1}$ and find the matrices $J(f)(ln2,2)$ and $ J(f^{-1})(5,3)$.

I have tried to use the condition for $f$ to be a bijective function, that is $f$ is bijective iff for any $(u,v) \in B$, there is only one pair $(x,y)\in (0,\infty)^2$ such that $f(x,y)=(u,v)$ and I have tried to find a bijective function that proves me this, but I cannot explicitate this expression. Also, finding the determinant of $J(f)(x,y)$ didn`t help me much.
I am new to this type of problems and I do not have many examples, could you provide a full proof, or at least in the form of an answer, such that it would serve as a model for similar problems I encounter? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(0,\infty)^2=:A$. When $(x,y)\in A$ then
$$f(x,y):=\bigl(y^2\cosh x,\>y^2\sinh x)\in B$$
since $y^2>0$ and $\cosh x>\sinh x>0$. It follows that $f$ is a $C^1$ map from $A$ to $B$.

Conversely: Given $(u,v)\in B$ we have to prove that there is exactly one point $(x,y)\in A$ with
$$y^2\cosh x=u,\qquad y^2\sinh x=v\ .\tag{1}$$
From $(1)$ we immediately obtain
$$\tanh x={v\over u},\qquad u^2-v^2=y^4(\cosh^2 x-\sinh^2 x)=y^4\ ,$$
so that an $(x,y)\in A$ satisfying these equations is uniquely determined by
$$x={\rm artanh}{v\over u},\qquad y=(u^2-v^2)^{1/4}\ .\tag{2}$$
Strictly one now has to prove that for this $(x,y)$ we indeed have $f(x,y)=(u,v)$. For this proof you need a formula that computes $\cosh x$ when $\tanh x$ is given. I leave this to you.

Formula $(2)$ is already an explicit expression for $f^{-1}: \>B\to A$, and you can see that $f^{-1}$ is $C^1$ as well. It follows that $f: \>A\to B$ is indeed a diffeomorphism.

Computing the two required Jacobian matrices is a mechanical matter.